# Subtle curve on bottom of div

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve a **subtle curve** at the bottom of my `<div>`

Here is an example image of what i am trying to achieve

[image]

I tried to achieve it by doing this :

```
section.box{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
}
```

This is what I'm getting.

[image]

What can i do to change this?

### UPDATE

**What I have tried :**

```css
.box{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}

.round-bottom{
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <section class="round-bottom">
      
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please put your code using code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You could achive that by adjustion `border-radius` in your CSS rules like :

```
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%  /100%;
```

And by adding shadows like :

```
  box-shadow: 1px -3px 22px 0px;
```

Hope this helps.

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
}
div#box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ea3e5e;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%  /100%;
  box-shadow: 1px -3px 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use Ellipse border to `border-radius` you can learn more about it please be refer this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp

```css
#rcorners9 {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 95% 65%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 95% 65%;
    background: #FF3352;
    padding: 20px; 
    width:100%;
    height: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 1px -5px 22px ;
}
```

```html
<p id="rcorners9"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have personally achieved this result by extending the image beyond the edge of the screen like this:

```
.curved {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 95% 65%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 95% 65%;
}
.full-width {
    min-width: 150%;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -25vw;
    margin-right: -25vw;
    justify-content: center;
}
```